# Implementing Import/Export feature on IWSz 9.3

Tags: workload-scheduler

User has applied UI48340 and would like to get more information around this feature that they would like to use. They are looking for technical references, materials on how to set-up/configure and use this feature

Regards,
Reyland

Answer (score 0):

we published a blog that helps to use the new feature supplied with the UI48340 PTF. It allows to export and import applications so that they can be shared with other Workload Scheduler for z/OS environments. The blog is published on the Workload Automation Community at the following link:

http://www.workloadautomation-community.com/blogs/devops-scenario-to-deploy-applications-to-another-zos-environment

I think this will help you to set up and use the new feature.
Best regards,
Raffaella

Comment: While it is OK for an answer to refer to an external resource for extra information, the answer itself should at least contain a basic solution to the problem.